# Sorting Excel Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA.  I have a spreadsheet with three columns.  Column A is Soldiers Name.   column B is Basic Soldier Information (Enlisted, Date, Regiment, Captured, died, etc.   Column C has additional information about a few Soldiers.   I would like to Sort By name and keep the additional Columns/rows intact and associated with the name.  I have tried building table and sorting but no luck.  Hoping this could be accomplished with VBA.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need this done in VBA? Why not just sort in the app?

Comment: Welcome @g.zell. Take a look at this how-to. It should do the trick and avoid the unnecessary complexity that VBA adds: https://www.contextures.com/xlSort01.html#sorttwo

Comment: You can also use the `Record Macro` function in the `Developers Tab` to record you performing a sort. There are a number of `How Tos` on the internet.